# I want to create two drop down list. In one when I select a category corresponding sub category should appear in next

Tags: jquery, html

I am doing a project in **codeigniter**.

I am dynamically getting values for two drop down boxes in one of which when I select a category the corresponding su category should appear in the nect drop drown. I have successfully retrieved the values using function on selection of the main category need to know on how to put it back to form

My controller:

```
public function subcategorylist($id)
{
    $this->load->model('Categorymodel');
    $response = array();
    $response = $this->Categorymodel->getsubcategoryrdetailsbyid($id);
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

My Model:

```
public function getsubcategoryrdetailsbyid($id)
{
    $subcategoryrdetailsbyidarray = array();                
    $id=intval($id);

    $sql = "select id, fk_parent_id, name from tbl_categories where fk_parent_id = ?";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql,array($id));

    if($query->num_rows())
    {
        $rows = $query->result();

        foreach($rows as $tempsubcategorybyidarray)
        {
            $smallsubcatdetailsarray = array();

            $smallsubcatdetailsarray['id'] = $tempsubcategorybyidarray->id;
            $smallsubcatdetailsarray['fk_parent_id'] = $tempsubcategorybyidarray->fk_parent_id;
            $smallsubcatdetailsarray['name'] = $tempsubcategorybyidarray->name;
            array_push($subcategoryrdetailsbyidarray, $smallsubcatdetailsarray);
        }
    }

    return $subcategoryrdetailsbyidarray;
}
```

My view:

```
 <div class="box-body">
     <div class="form-group">                                   
                <label>Sub Category</label>                                
                        <select class="form-control select product" style="width: 100%;" name="option1" id="option">
                            <option value="" id="subcat">Select Sub Category</option>  
                        </select>
      </div>    
  </div>
```

My script:

```
<script> 
       function getsubcat(sel) { 
          var id = sel.value; alert (id); 
          var myurl="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?/Category/subcategorylist/"+id; 
          $.post(myurl).done(function(data) { 
             alert(data); $('#subcat').html(data); 
          }); 
       } 
</script>
```

---

Comment: simplest way is to write the onChange function over parent dropdown so whenever parent changes, load data from server and populate child dropdown. if no value is selected in parent the child can be either hidden or have no select options

Comment: I have did this and I got the values from db. I want to print it to the next drop down

Comment: what is the format of data.. Or what data is return..

Comment: use $("childdropdown-selector").html(generated-options)

Comment: you have to rebuild the options html from received data and replace current options with generated options

Comment: Could you please re generate the script for me

Answer (score 0):

hello I don't know how php work,
but I try to explain how you can add option in select from data.
if your data returns like this

data = [{id:1,fk_parent_id:'xyz',name:'xyz'},{id:1,fk_parent_id:'xyz',name:'xyz'}]

than you can try like this

```
$.each(data,function(key){$('#option').append('<option value='+data[key].id+'>'+data[key].name+'</option>')})
```

sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hozs2uwp/

Thanks

Comment: Ok let me try. But how can I get the option value and what does key refers to

Comment: key is index of your json that we iterate in $.each().

Comment: the slelection is just getting highlighted

Comment: <script>
function getsubcat(sel)
{
 var id = sel.value;
 alert (id);
 var myurl="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?/Category/subcategorylist/"+id;
 
  $.post(myurl).done(function(data)
   {
    alert(data);
   $.each(data,function(key)
   {
    $('#option').append('<option'+data[key].fk_parent_id+'>'+data[key].name+'</option>')
   });
   });
 
}
</script>

Comment: the return data is in the same form as you have mentioned the earliesr comments

Comment: It is not working. The slection is just getting highlighted on clicking